# feed reader in primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces, rss-reader

below is the code for feed reader of primefaces which is throwing an error which says
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/syndication/io/XmlReader

```
<h:body>
    <p:feedReader size="20" value="http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/sports" var="feed">  
<h:outputText value="#{feed.title}" style="font-weight: bold"/>  
<br />  
<h:outputText value="#{feed.description.value}" escape="false"/>  
<p:separator />
```

i searched for the same n found that some ROME library has to be included in the classpath. 
i downloaded the rome jar file n included it in my project but still it gives the same error
what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u add jdom jar? If not add.Als try changing the version of the rome jar.i.e try 0.9.

Comment: i added rome-0.9.jar now it gives me java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom/JDOMException what should i include?

Comment: 2.0.1 is the latest jdom version i guess, can u pls send the link for 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the library using run time tool or jdk tool

using `runtime` tool

java -cp `Your class_List`

using `jdk tools`

ex:
C:> java/jdb/javac/javah -classpath C:\java\MyClasses;C:\java\OtherClasses

or you can set `CLASSPATH` env variable

ex:set CLASSPATH=path1;path2